# Angular 9 rxJs - How to use combine/merge statements to retrieve observable values and pass to another function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that let's me open a snackbar:

```
this.snackBarService.open(title, body);
```

`title` and `body` are strings.

The issue I have is that they both need to be translated from keys, and the translation service returns an Observable:

```
  /**
   * Returns an observable for a translation based on the key
   *
   * @param key the translation key
   */
  private getTranslation(key: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.translocoService.selectTranslate(key, {}, 'auth');
  }
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141648/rxjs-how-do-i-use-the-result-of-one-observable-in-another-and-then-process-thos) led me to thinking I could use `mergeMap` and `combineLatest` before calling the open method, something like this:

```
  this.getTranslation('snackbars.username.success.title').pipe(
    mergeMap(title => {
      return combineLatest(
        of(title),
        this.getTranslation('snackbars.username.success.body')
      );
    }),
    map(([title, body]) => {
      console.log('here', title, body);
      this.snackBarService.open(title, body);
    })
  );
```

but nothing happens...the console doesn't log anything :(

It would be somewhat tedious to have to subscribe and unsubscribe from both calls to getTranslation...so is there some easy way to just get the values from both the observable and pass them to the snackbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could do enough only with a `forkJoin`. Try the following

```js
forkJoin([
  this.getTranslation('snackbars.username.success.title'), 
  this.getTranslation('snackbars.username.success.body')
]).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log('here', response[0], response[1]);
    this.snackBarService.open(response[0], response[1]);
  }
);
```

`forkJoin` only emits if both the observables complete. If not then you could use `combineLatest` and pipe in a `take(1)` to use only the first values emitted from the observables and complete.

```js
combineLatest([
  this.getTranslation('snackbars.username.success.title'), 
  this.getTranslation('snackbars.username.success.body')
]).pipe(
    take(1)
  ).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log('here', response[0], response[1]);
    this.snackBarService.open(response[0], response[1]);
  }
);
```

Comment: I had tried forkJoin earlier, and was stuck. Thanks for pointing out it only emits upon completion (as I now know the translation service does not complete!). Your updates answer with combineLatest works perfectly. Thank you for the fast response!