# How to call one service after another service sucess condition in Rxjs Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

How to call one service after another success call. like

```
this.data.getUser().subscribe((res: any) => {
  if (res.id === 1) {
    this.data.getTask().subscribe((da: any)=> {
      console.log('task', da);
    });
  }
});
```

Can we write a better way of this code using the Rxjs Operator ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `concatMap`, `mergeMap` in this case also `switchMap` would work as well.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141648/rxjs-how-do-i-use-the-result-of-one-observable-in-another-and-then-process-thos

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter operator, to filter the response only when you get `res.id === 1`.

And then You can use any of the `map` operators such as `switchMap` , `concatMap` etc.

I used `switchMap` which cancels the ongoing request/stream when a new event comes.
To use multiple operators on a single Observable we can use `pipe` operator to merge them.

```js
this.data.getUser().pipe(
         filter((res: any) => res.id === 1),
         switchMap((res: any) => {
            return this.data.getTask();
         })
        ).subscribe(da => {
         console.log('task', da);
       });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we are getting the user's response not task one.

Comment: The example you gave, uses the user's response `res.id === 1` to send another request. Correct?. I've used that to filter the results and then get the task response.